# How to feed Json response into an Empty ant design table?

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

I am quite new to react and want to feed my json response which i got from an api into an empty ant-design table and I am getting no clue on how to do that?

i have already mapped id with name but also want all other columns and into the table format of ant design.

JSon response

```
[
    {
        "id": 9685,
        "name": "Mukesh  Rai",
        "count of sub": 3,
        "count of int": 2,
        "count of po": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2085,
        "name": "Abhyudaya Singh Panwar",
        "count of sub": 1049,
        "count of int": 17,
        "count of po": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 7087,
        "name": "Amit Kumar Sharma",
        "count of sub": 363,
        "count of int": 68,
        "count of po": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 2100,
        "name": "Aditya Kumar",
        "count of sub": 724,
        "count of int": 5,
        "count of po": 1
     }
]
```

component file

```
  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/marketer_details/")
      .then(response=>{
        console.log(response)
        this.setState({posts: response.data})
      })
      .catch(error=> {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }

render() {
    const { posts } = this.state
    return(
      <div>
        List of Posts
        {
          posts.length ?
          posts.map(post => <div key = {post.id}>{post.name}</div>) : 
          null
        }
      </div>
    )
```

//Wanted all other columns as well

```
    render(){
    const columns = [
      {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name',
        width: '30%',
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps('name'),
      },
      {
        title: 'Count of Submissions',
        dataIndex: 'Count',
        key: 'sub',
        width: '20%',
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps('sub'),
      },
      {
        title: 'Count of Interviews',
        dataIndex: 'Count',
        key: 'int',
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps('int'),
      },
      {
        title: 'Count of PO',
        dataIndex: 'Count',
        key: 'po',
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps('po'),
      },
    ];
    return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.posts} />;
  }
}
}
export default App
```

I am unable to understand how the multiple mapping could be done against each column row.

Comment: How come you have two `return` statements for the function?

Comment: I am sry i was trying to depict what i have done already and it didn't get compartmentalized

Comment: Dataindex should match property name of your json..
And add one more flag loading: true in your state and set it to false when data was loaded... Initialy your data shows loading and once you get data from backend it will display data <Table columns={columns} loading={this.state.loading} dataSource={this.state.posts} />

Answer (score 0):

The `Table` component takes a column structure as argument.

Here, `dataIndex` refers to the index in the data that is to be referenced for the column, `key` is intended to remain unique across column names.

In your case, the columns array could be:

```
const columns = [
    {
      name: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name"
    },
    {
      name: "Count of submissions",
      dataIndex: "count of sub"
    },
    {
      name: "Count of interviews",
      dataIndex: "count of int"
    },
    {
      name: "Count of PO",
      dataIndex: "count of po"
    }
  ];
```

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-56624806-30hw7)

Comment: But the thing is how to feed the raw json data in these coulmns?? Should i iterate over the list and push the data or is there any other way i can do it??

Comment: That's what you use the `dataSource` field for, feed the raw json to that field

Comment: You don't have to do anything, this attribute dataSource={this.state.posts} gonna take care

Comment: but i think its not gonna fetch data from api and put it into subsequent columns

Comment: @HrithikBaishakhiya it is going to do that